# wp_delete_attachment

Tags: functions

Im' trying to delete all attachments of a custom post type on post deletion using the before_delete_post hook.

It works ok except that if I add another function to override the upload dir it doesn't delete the files.

Here is the code in use:

```
function set_upload_dir( $args ) {
    $id = ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : '' );
    if( $id ) {
       $newdir = '/' . get_post_type( $id );
       $args['path']    = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['path'] );
       $args['url']     = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['url'] );
       $args['subdir']  = $newdir;
       $args['path']   .= $newdir;
       $args['url']    .= $newdir;
       return $args;
   }
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'set_upload_dir' );


function delete_post_media($post_id) {
    //if ('galleries' != get_post_type($id)) return;
    $attachments = get_attached_media( '', $post->ID );
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        if ( false === wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, true ) ) {
        }
    }
}
add_action('before_delete_post', ' delete_post_media');
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'delete_post_media');
```

Any thoughts on what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Replace your current upload filter with the one below
2. Create a new custom post and upload some files
3. Check the files have been moved to the correct uploads folder
4. Delete the custom post and then check the files have been deleted

New uploads filter function:

```
function set_upload_dir( $args ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) && $post_id = absint( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) {
        if ( $post = get_post( $post_id ) ) {               
            if ( $post->post_type !== 'attachment' ) {
                $args['subdir'] = "/$post->post_type"; // Must be preceded with slash
                $args['path']   = $args['basedir'] . $args['subdir'];
                $args['url']    = $args['baseurl'] . $args['subdir'];
            }
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```

The main differences between this and yours are:

1. We aggressively check the post context (`post_id`) is valid and that it's not an attachment in itself. Remember, this filter is called all over the place, not just when an image is uploaded.
2. Use the `basedir` and `baseurl` arguments instead of string replacing. Your paths could otherwise end up with double slashes (or even missing ones).

Once an image is uploaded, it's `subdir` is stored in the database, and WordPress will only ever use `basedir` when attempting to retrieve the filepath.

In other words, things won't break if `wp_upload_dir` is called for a custom post type attachment out of context, and the returned `subdir` is not actually where the file resides.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! Is there any way I can go further by having a folder structure like this: "custom_post_type/post_id" ?

Comment: Of course. Just change `"/$post->post_type"` to `"/$post->post_type/$post->ID"`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and it does work but it only deletes files not the actual parent folder ($post->ID). Any idea why?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing in core that will delete an uploads folder once it becomes empty. You'll need to implement that yourself.