# blank page when trying to change upload directory

Tags: php

Working with wordpress 4.2.2, when I use this code in child theme function.php to change the attachments upload directory according to each post type :

```
function wpse_16722_type_upload_dir( $args ) {
// Get the current post_id
$id = ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : '' );
if( $id ) {    
   // Set the new path depends on current post_type
   $newdir = '/' . get_post_type( $id );
   $args['path']    = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['path'] ); //remove default subdir
   $args['url']     = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['url'] );      
   $args['subdir']  = $newdir;
   $args['path']   .= $newdir; 
   $args['url']    .= $newdir; 
   return $args;
   }
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_16722_type_upload_dir' );
```

I get a blank page!! there is no empty rows in the function.php and the problem appears only after adding this code. I really need it to organize my upload folder, but without a blank page. is there any solution?

Comment: Set debug to true

Comment: Check error_logs and like @PieterGoosen said, enable debug in wp-config to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a better function, your paths are broken - see [this answer for reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188149/1685):

```
function wpse_16722_type_upload_dir( $args ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) && $post_id = absint( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) {
        if ( $post = get_post( $post_id ) ) {               
            if ( $post->post_type !== 'attachment' ) {
                $args['subdir'] = "/$post->post_type"; // Must be preceded with slash
                $args['path']   = $args['basedir'] . $args['subdir'];
                $args['url']    = $args['baseurl'] . $args['subdir'];
            }
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Erreur file.pdf The file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/communications.

Comment: Permissions error. Make sure `uploads` is writable by PHP. Worst case scenario, set to `777`.

Comment: permissions set to 777 but error still happening

Comment: Have you recursively set `777`? i.e. `communications` needs to be `777` too.

Comment: yes i did that but error still

Comment: Something is out of whack on your server. Check your logs.

Comment: where logs can be found?

Comment: How should I know!? Every setup is different. Check your hosting control panel.